# Is there any alternative to this error - A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using Observable to get data from Http endpoints. I am getting this error `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` if I am not adding return statement in this line `return https.get(urls[i], res =>`. On adding the return statement here the urls array is not able access the second endpoint. Is there any way this could be solved?

```
const https = require('https');
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  constructor() {}

  message = new ProductMessage();
  publishMessages(productEvent: ProductEvent): Observable<any> {
    let json = '';
const url = this.configService.get('SITEMAP_ENDPOINT');
    const urls = [
      'https://' + url + '/blc,
      'https://' + url + '/eye
    ];
    try {
      for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        return https.get(urls[i], res => {  ---------> How can I remove return? 
          res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            json += chunk;
          });
          res.on('end', function() {
            const result = JSON.parse(json);
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < result[i].products.length; j++) {
                if (
                  //some condition
                ) {
                  for (let k = 0; k < productEvent.productCodes.length; k++) {
                    if (
                       //some condition

                    ) {
                      console.log(result[i].products[j].productCode);
                    }
                  }
                }else {
                  console.log('No data found');
                  return;
                }
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare the function to have a return type other than `void` if you don't want it to return anything?

Comment: I am not sure how to mention ```void``` here

Comment: `publishMessages(productEvent: ProductEvent): void` should be your first attempt

Comment: Without using Observable I am getting syntax error at JSON.parse. Looks like observable is must. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do here? I'm especially curious about the for loop with a return inside. That must be a mistake???

Comment: Its like I am accessing the data from the endpoint, then I am comparing some locally defined data with the data in the service. If they match up i would like to return them. But as of now my 1st priority is looping through both the endpoints

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

You are returning nothing in case your try block fails. But you declared your methods return type to be always of type `Observable<any>`. Either return an observable from your catch block as well, or declare the methods return type as `Observable<any> | void`.

Beware though that your code will most likely not work as expected. In your try block your are doing a for loop with a return statement within. Since a return statement exits the function, the for loop is actually without any effect as it will only loop once and then return from the method immediately.

**Elaborating on your Observables**

What you most likely want to do is combine your observables in some way. Now, there are multiple ways to do this, but the simpliest solution would be to `forkJoin` them. I suggest you read up on `rxjs` a bit more.
Secondly, I strongly suggest you use the angular `HttpClient` within the `HttpClientModule` to do your HTTP Request (don't worry, the `HttpClient` will do HTTPS Requests if you provide HTTPS URLs.

Your code could then look something like this:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {forkJoin, Observable, of} from 'rxjs'; 
import {map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {
  constructor(
    private readonly http:HttpClient
  ) {}


  publishMessages(productEvent: ProductEvent): Observable<Array<any>> { // Notice the return type is now an Array of all responses!
    let json = '';
    const url:string = 'some-url.com';
    const urls:Array<string> = [
      'https://' + url + '/blc',
      'https://' + url + '/eye'
    ];

    // Takes an array of observables and combines them into 1 which only emits when ALL observables inside complete,
    return forkJoin( 
      urls.map(urlToLoad => // Map your Array of URLs to an Array of Observables that do the HTTP(S) Request
        this.http.get(urlToLoad).pipe( // Create the HTTP Request per URL inside your array
          map(apiResult => { // apiResult is the result from your API Endpoint already parsed as a json Object
             // here you can transform your apiResult to any fitting object you want, if the json is already what you want, just leave the whole map function out
             return apiResult;
          }),
          catchError(err => { // This is run when the API call failed for some reason (e.g. http code >= 400)
            console.log(err); 
            return of(null); // Transform the error to a positive response to not break the forkJoin, depends on how you want to handle your error though
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I would remove the return and declare Observable as void so that it loops through 2nd endpoint, but after doing this I am getting data from 1st endpoint and then getting this error  ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 18140295
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)```. Any suggestions?

Comment: @osama I updated my answer to give a bit more of an explanation on how to solve your issue. The error message your are getting is most likely because all your API requests write to the same json object, hence the result is not a correct json - every request is writing into the same object after all. If you use the Angular HttpClient, this problem will be taken care of for you.